Usin ToXmlGenerator to serialize a XML file
I need to serialize an XML, the input I want is something like:
 <item id="123">description</item>

I have a serializer that has the following code:
        toXmlGenerator.writeFieldName("item");
        toXmlGenerator.writeStartObject();
        toXmlGenerator.setNextIsAttribute(true);
        toXmlGenerator.writeFieldName("id");
        toXmlGenerator.writeString(element.getId());
        toXmlGenerator.setNextIsAttribute(false);
        toXmlGenerator.writeStringField("",element.getValue());
        toXmlGenerator.writeEndObject();

with the above I get :
  <item id="123">
              <>description</>
            </item>

I've tried different options with  toXmlGenerator.writeStringField("",element.getValue());
but nothing works, I tried toXmlGenerator.writeString(element.getValue());
but I get the following error:
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not write String value, expecting field name
Is there a way to do this I am missing?

What is element.getValue() returning?

There is a setNextIsUnwrapped(boolean) method that enables a value output without the node name.
toXmlGenerator.setNextIsUnwrapped(true);

It should be placed before writeStringField():
toXmlGenerator.setNextIsAttribute(false);
toXmlGenerator.setNextIsUnwrapped(true);
toXmlGenerator.writeStringField("", element.getValue());
toXmlGenerator.writeEndObject();

